# how to set comma for double number in kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

```
$("#kendoGridView").kendoGrid({
                            width: 1500,
                            dataSource: data.d,
                            resizable: true,
                            rowTemplate:
                            height: 790,
                            dataBound: dbGrid,
                            selectable: true,
                            columns: [
                                            { title: 'Revenue', field: 'Revenue', width: '20%', sortable: true },
                                            { title: 'postals', field: 'postals', width: '12%', sortable: true },
                                            { title: 'MQC', field: 'MQC', width: '12%', sortable: true },
                                      ]
                        });
```

i am binding values from the database to kendoGrid.i want to set comma separator to all column numbers in grid(ex 458690 to 4,58,690).i have read NumberFormating concept in kendoui,but i have not got sufficiant information.how can i set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of the culture that you are using but basically, you just have to add in your column a field `format` according to [the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) :

```
$("#kendoGridView").kendoGrid({
    width: 1500,
    dataSource: data.d,
    resizable: true,
    rowTemplate:
    height: 790,
    dataBound: dbGrid,
    selectable: true,
    columns: [
        // Here I have added the format field
        { title: 'Revenue', field: 'Revenue', width: '20%', sortable: true, format: "{0:c3}" },
        { title: 'postals', field: 'postals', width: '12%', sortable: true },
        { title: 'MQC', field: 'MQC', width: '12%', sortable: true },
    ]
});
```

I have created this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AHCbq/ .

---

**EDIT :**

It seems that even with a correct culture, some decimal fields are not correctly interpreted in the grid and that we can not applies a custom format.

In order to workaround this issue, we have to create a custom parser in order to force the field to be seen as a decimal field. I have updated my previous fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AHCbq/7/ .

This is achieved by adding a parser in the `datasource.schema.parse` which transform the string in a number :

```
parse : function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i, val) {
        // Here I convert the string in a decimal number
        val.Freight = +val.Freight;
    });
    return data;
}
```

Comment: hello samuel this 839009.378(double) value is coming from database.i have written format:"{0:c3}" for column but " , " separator is not applying to those values.is this line of code kendo.culture("en-US"); or kendo.culture("de-DE"); necessary to write.?please give reply

Comment: It seems that it is not mandatory... But I have played a little with the format and I have seen that with their data (my fiddle relies on kendo UI data) contains a column with a decimal field - Freight - and we can not format it with the field format as indicated above. So I have updated my post in order to add another solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [template for your column](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnstemplate-string) and combine it with the [kendo.format](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#format) method.

e.g.

```
 columns: [
     {
         field: "Salary",
         template: '#= kendo.format("{0:c}",Salary) #'
    }
 ]
```

You can use most of the things [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), the method is inspired by the C# method.

Comment: i have already taken row template for binding images to grid.so its not accepting second time .if i comment row template (for image) this is working fine....isn't possible to use two row templates for grid.?